# Looping through an array in PHP not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I am retrieving the following array, which is the options list for a product, using the  bigCommerece API.  Using `echo $curlProductOptions` I see the following echoed to the screen:

```
[
    {
        "id": 412,
        "option_id": 37,
        "display_name": "testSteveMemory",
        "sort_order": 0,
        "is_required": true
    },
    {
        "id": 413,
        "option_id": 34,
        "display_name": "Hard Drive (desktop)",
        "sort_order": 1,
        "is_required": true
    },
    {
        "id": 414,
        "option_id": 24,
        "display_name": "Include Keyboard & Mouse",
        "sort_order": 2,
        "is_required": true
    },
    {
        "id": 415,
        "option_id": 33,
        "display_name": "Memory",
        "sort_order": 3,
        "is_required": true
    }
]
```

So I am presuming I have an array within `$curlProductOptions` containing the above data.

I now need to loop through each element and `echo` each 'option_id'.

I have tried :

```
foreach($curlProductOptions['option_id'] as $value)
{echo $value;}
```

and:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($curlProductOptions); ++$i)
{echo 'optionID ='.$curlProductOptions[$i].option_id.'<br>';}
```

I also tried just to echo one of the elements.

```
echo $curlProductOptions['option_id'][0];
echo $curlProductOptions[0]['option_id'];
```

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: That looks like a *JSON encoded string*, not a PHP array. You must `json_decode` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
$curlProductOptions = json_decode($curlProductOptions, true);
foreach($curlProductOptions as $value){
  echo $value['option_id'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. each answer was correct what is the correct eticat for selecting the correct answer and do I just +1 on each useful answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You have json encoded string. So you need to [**`json_decode`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first .

try like this:

```
$curlProductOptions = json_decode($curlProductOptions,true);//create associative array
foreach($curlProductOptions['option_id'] as $value){
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Does this only work on new PHP version? In 5.3 it doesn't work